# Scikit dendrogram: How to disable ouput?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

If I run `dendrogram` from the scikit libary:

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, dendrogram
# ...
X = np.asarray(X)
Z = linkage(X, 'single', 'correlation')
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
dendrogram(Z, color_threshold=0.7)
```

I get *a ton* of `print` output in my ipython notebook:

```
{'color_list': ['g',
  'r',
  'c',
  'm',
  'y',
   ...
   0.70780175324891315,
   0.70172263980890581],
  [0.0, 0.54342622932769225, 0.54342622932769225, 0.0],
  [0.0, 0.46484932243120658, 0.46484932243120658, 0.0],
  ...
  177,
  196,
  82,
  19,
  108]}
```

How can I disable this? I'm only interested in the actual dendrogram.

Comment: never used it but the docs: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html state you can pass `p` and `truncate` args which might help you control the verbosity of the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to redirect print to nothing:

```
import os
import sys
f = open(os.devnull, 'w')
temp = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = f

# print is disabled here

sys.stdout = temp

# print works again!
```